# Show Checkbox was checked in CGridView Yii 1.1

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, cgridview

I have a CGridView with Checkbox column like this:

```
array(
      'name' => 'updated',
      'id' => 'selectedIds',
      'value' => '$data->id',
      'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
      'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => [
           'class' => 'checkbox-ajax'
      ]
),
```

and I have a field `updated` DB with 0 if not update and 1 if updated.

Now I want to check the row in CGridView if field updated = 1, this row will be bold or highlight this.

Any solutions for this case?

Comment: see answer below, hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter in field's array. Here i added one more parameter in array i.e. `checked`. See below solution.

```
array(
            'name' => 'updated',
            'header' => 'updated',
            'id' => 'selectedIds',
            'value' => '$data->id',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'checked' => function($data){ return ($data->updated == 1) ? true:false;},
            'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => [
                'class' => 'checkbox-ajax'
            ]
        ),
```

Comment: I use this line `'checked' => function($data){ return ($data->updated == 1) ? true:false;}'`
But when I tick, all rows have checked before had uncheck. How is it happended?

Comment: by default in `CCheckBoxColumn` user can select only 1 check box, you need to add one more parameter in array i.e. `'selectableRows' => 2` for multiple checkbox selection.

Comment: check weather it updating more that one row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100943/discussion-between-chetan-ameta-and-francis).